# Is there a way to determine if Android app is running full screen?

Tags: android

i was just wondering if there was a simple way to see if an application running on android is currently in full screen.  is there a way to query android to see if you're currently in full screen mode or something like that?

Answer (score 17):

Just to complete on Sigwann answer:

```
boolean fullScreen = (getWindow().getAttributes().flags & WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN) != 0;
boolean forceNotFullScreen = (getWindow().getAttributes().flags & WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN) != 0;
boolean actionbarVisible = getActionBar().isShowing();
```

Comment: Worth being careful on the last line there with the getActionBar().isShowing() - if you've disabled the action bar in the theme rather than just hiding it, then getActionBar() can return null.

Comment: I am not sure why emulator pixel 4 API 29 in Android Studio, boolean fullScreen = (getWindow().getAttributes().flags & WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN) != 0; return false when I used an activity with FullScreen = true style. Anyone meet the same problem?

Answer (score 12):

I guess Commonsware wanted to say getWindow().getAttributes() and not getWindow().getFlags(); since getFlags does not exist as far as I know. At least it is not in doc.

you need to read getWindow().getAttributes().flags, which is an int.

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
int i = lp.flags;
```

FLAG_FULLSCREEN = 1024 according to android documentation.
so your flag is the 11th bite of lp.flags

if this bite = 1, full screen is activated.

Answer (score 10):

Following the info of Sigwann, here my code....

```
public boolean isFullScreen() {
    int flg = getWindow().getAttributes().flags;
    boolean flag = false;       
    if ((flg & WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN) {
        flag = true;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Simple, but works!

Comment: Still it's magic number. Better to use: WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN

Answer (score 9):

You can figure out if your `Activity` is running fullscreen via `getWindow().getFlags()`.

However, if by "an application" you are referring to somebody else's application, then the answer is no.

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice hack, using the absolute position of a `View` on screen. Just check the position of any top left view of your layout (can be invisible), if it's on position 0,0. Like this:

```
/**
 * Check if fullscreen is activated by a position of a top left View
 * @param topLeftView View which position will be compared with 0,0
 * @return
 */
public static boolean isFullscreen(View topLeftView) {
    int location[] = new int[2];
    topLeftView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    return location[0] == 0 && location[1] == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you may use some thing like this;

```
findViewById(android.R.id.content).getHeight();
    getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
```

and check for equality;
hope this helps;

Answer (score 2):

As of api11 there is now a way to detect that using a [View.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener%28android.view.View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener%29)

The listener interface documentation notes the following:

> Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when the status bar changes visibility. This reports **global** changes to the system UI state, not what the application is requesting.

I don't know if there's a way to do it prior to Honeycomb.

Comment: This doesn't work if the application is made fullscreen in onCreate.

Answer (score 2):

> is there a way to query android to see if you're currently in full
>   screen mode or something like that?

You can get if your app is running in full screen;:

```
boolean isFullScreen = (getWindow().getAttributes().flags & WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN) != 0;
```

> i was just wondering if there was a simple way to see if an
>   application running on android

if you are tryin to get if an application is running in full screen that´s not possible programatically only visually.

Comment: WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

if you want to **Respond to UI visibility changes** for all apps including yours,  use this code

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();//you can also use findViewById to get the view
decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener
        (new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
        // Note that system bars will only be "visible" if none of the
        // LOW_PROFILE, HIDE_NAVIGATION, or FULLSCREEN flags are set.
        if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
            // TODO: The system bars are visible. Make any desired
            // adjustments to your UI, such as showing the action bar or
            // other navigational controls.
        } else {
            // TODO: The system bars are NOT visible. Make any desired
            // adjustments to your UI, such as hiding the action bar or
            // other navigational controls.
        }
    }
});
```

[source of info](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/visibility#java)

Answer (score 0):

[Activity.hasWindowFocus()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#hasWindowFocus%28%29) tells you if your own activity is visible to the user. But, as CommonsWare notes, it's much harder to tell if *another* activity is on the top of the stack. You can try querying the `ActivityManager` (e.g, [ActivityManager.getProcessTasks()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRecentTasks%28int,%20int%29) ), but its methods don't provide an exact answer for your question.