# How to check if foreground app is running in full screen mode in Android?

Tags: android, fullscreen

My app uses a background service which appears according to certain trigger, i want its appearance features to be depended on the mode of the foreground activity (full screen or not)
Is there a way I can determine if the foreground activity is in Full Screen mode ?

I noticed the following question :
[Is there a way to determine if Android app is running full screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642914/is-there-a-way-to-determine-if-android-app-is-running-full-screen)
But it looks like it only checks for own activity and not for foreground activity.

Please notice it will probably not be my app/activity but another.

Comment: Have you got any solution to this requirement? I am also searching for the the same implementation.

Comment: Nope...Didn't find an answer.